# Kubernetes and Spring microservices: Query via UDP timed out after 5000 milliseconds

Tags: spring, kubernetes, microservices, spring-cloud, minikube

I'm trying to deploy my spring boot microservices to kubernetes cluster with minikube. I have **API GATEWAY** and **MICROSERVICE 1** all the requests go through the gateway on port 8765. But when I try to send an GET request to **MICROSERVISE 1** this is what happens in API GATEWAY Pod:

```
2022-10-17 14:55:06.871  INFO [api-gateway,b9d3c5287b749c70,b9d3c5287b749c70] 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] c.example.apigateway.log.LoggingFilter   : Path of the request received is this -> /api/v1/microservice1
2022-10-17 14:55:26.288 ERROR [api-gateway,,] 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [a8a10abb-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/api/v1/microservice1"

java.net.UnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'microservice1'
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1047) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
        *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/api/v1/microservice1" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
                at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1047) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1000) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$600(DnsResolveContext.java:66) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:467) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.tryFailure(DnsQueryContext.java:240) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext$4.run(DnsQueryContext.java:192) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:394) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.76.Final.jar!/:4.1.76.Final]
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverTimeoutException: [/10.96.0.10:53] query via UDP timed out after 5000 milliseconds (no stack trace available)
```

API Gateway yml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-gateway
  labels:
    app: api-gateway
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-gateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-gateway
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api-gateway
          image: usr/api-gateway-microservice
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "400Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8765
          env:
              - name: SPRING_ZIPKIN_BASEURL
                valueFrom: 
                  configMapKeyRef:
                    name: eureka-cm
                    key: SPRING_ZIPKIN_BASEURL
              - name: RABBIT_URI
                valueFrom: 
                  configMapKeyRef:
                    name: eureka-cm
                    key: RABBIT_URI
              - name: SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST
                valueFrom: 
                  configMapKeyRef:
                    name: eureka-cm
                    key: SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST
              - name: SPRING_ZIPKIN_SENDER_TYPE
                valueFrom: 
                  configMapKeyRef:
                    name: eureka-cm
                    key: SPRING_ZIPKIN_SENDER_TYPE
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-gateway-svc
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8765
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: api-gateway
```

API Gateway redirections config:

```
@Configuration
public class ApiGatewayConfiguration {


  @Bean
  public RouteLocator gatewayRouter(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
    return builder.routes()
        .route(p -> p.path("/api/v1/**")
            .uri("https://microservice1:8081"))
        .build();
  }
```